# Data.Vector module Cannot Be Found

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, module, cabal

I start a new project library with cabal. here is the .cabal file

```
cabal-version:      2.4

library
    exposed-modules:  MyLib
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.3.0
                    , vector
    hs-source-dirs:   src
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

I then use some Data.Vector functions inside my code. Here is the MyLib source

```hs
module MyLib (someFunc) where

import qualified Data.Vector as V

func :: [a] -> V.Vector a
func a = V.fromList a
```

But `Data.Vector` module remains underlined in red and this error is shown inside Vcode:

```
Could not load module ‘Data.Vector’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’.
```

the `func` function works when in `cabal repl`

when I try `cabal install vector` this error appears:

```
Wrote tarball sdist to
/home/. .. .tar.gz
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package vector because it does not
contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make sure
that it properly declares the components that you expect.
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? I told I understood the workings of cabal: I import a module as a dependency in .cabal, and I should be able to use it? why VSC does tell me he can't find it?

Comment: The fact that it works in `cabal repl` tells you that it's not just totally missing from your system. So it's extremely doubtful that trying more things to install it will help. It must be some sort of issue in the configuration of VSC (which I know nothing about, or I'd try to provide an actual answer). But one guess: have you loaded your "project" into VSC, or just the `MyLib.hs` file? If you just opened the single file, it may need some step to make VSC aware of the cabal file as well, without which it may have no way of knowing what packages you expect to be available in your project.

Comment: You can try pressing `F1` and then type `Restart Haskell HLS Server`. It will take some time to restart, but afterwards the errors might go away.